# Objective C multiply 2 int*

Tags: ios, objective-c

This code show this error `Invalid operands to binary expression ('int*' and 'int*')`

```
    int *a = 5;
    int *b = 3;
    int *c = a*b;
```

How I can multiply them, and Why is this a error?

Comment: int a;  remove asterisk symbol because int is a primitive data type not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are initializing `int*` with an `int` value. To multiply values and write them to another pointer, you should call the value of a stored in an address with `(*a)`

here is the example code for what you want to do:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *c = malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = 2;
*b = 3;
*c = (*a)*(*b);
printf("%d %d %d", *a,*b,*c);
free(a);
free(b);
free(c);
```

it prints 2 3 6 as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `asterisk` symbol because `int` is a primitive data type not an object. You can put `asterisk` symbol with objects not primitive data types.

Asterisk symbol is pointer symbol from the C language.

```
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;
    int c = a*b;
```

Comment: I will like to, but in the code I am using I cant change the declaration of the int

Comment: You have to remove asterisk symbol otherwise you will get compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

this is the C (primitive type) Integer type so you cannot declare with pointer.

Please find the below code :

> int a = 5;
>
> int b = 3;
>
> int c = (a*b);

Thanks